# How do I have swipe left delete swipe right edit buttons off canvas?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, angularjs

I might redefine what the buttons do when they are clicked but that is irrelevant.  I do not need help setting up ng-click events come on people.  That part is easy.  I am struggling big time getting the animation effects that I want.  The application is in ionic so naturally I am working toward an AngularJS solution all of the examples out there are just a bit off.

I manged to piece together information and construct this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swipe left to delete implementation using AngularJs</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('ngSwipeLeftExample', ['ngTouch']);

        app.controller('SampleSwipe', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
            // $scope.swipeLeft=false;
            // $scope.swipeRight=false;
            $scope.delete = function() {
                alert('bbb');
                // $scope.swipeLeft=true;
                // $scope.swipeRight=true;
            }
            $scope.edit = function() {
                alert('aaa');
                // $scope.swipeLeft=true;
                // $scope.swipeRight=true;
            }
            $scope.clickedTable = function() {
                // alert('clicked table');
                // $scope.swipeLeft=false;
                // $scope.swipeRight=false;
            }
        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ngSwipeLeftExample" ng-controller="SampleSwipe">
    <table ng-init="swipeLeft = false; swipeRight = false;" data-ng-swipe-right="swipeRight = true" data-ng-swipe-left="swipeLeft = true" data-ng-click="" border=1 width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="100px">
                <div ng-show="swipeRight" >
                    <button ng-click="edit()" style="height: 44px;width: 109px;border: 0;background-color: green; color: white;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;cursor:pointer;">Edit</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div  ng-click="clickedTable()">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>aaaa</td><td>bbbb</td><td>cccc</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>aaaa</td><td>bbbb</td><td>cccc</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="100px">
                <div ng-show="swipeLeft" >
                    <button ng-click="delete()" style="height: 44px;width: 109px;border: 0;background-color: red; color: white;font-size: 18px;font-weight: bold;cursor:pointer;" align="right">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

But I don't really want to ng-hide the buttons I just want to size the record so that the html block in the middle column (I will put whatever in there it doesn't really matter what I put in there) should be sized to fit the page (width=100% I guess)  Then the edit and delete buttons being off canvas can be swiped left or right so the user can see them and click them.  I think this can be done with transitions somehow.  But nothing seems to work.  I am really not a CSS guy at all mostly I just piece my css together to get something almost what I want and then hand it over to my UI guy to fix it.  But he doensn't know how to do this either.

It seems like most ios and android apps work this way when there is a list and you swipe left to delete but it seems nobody wants to share the wisdom of how to do this correctly.

Let me guess soeone will reply that you are confused about my question and do not know what I am asking even though it is totally clear?  Correct?

[image]

Comment: Bare in mind I know mobile devices don't usually have the border around it in your typical app, much of what you see is just so I can see what is going on.  These stylng issues are minor and I really hope you will not comment on them and stay focused on the problem at hand.

Comment: There's no "off canvas" on iOS/Android app. Just some useful method built-in.